# Polymer 0.5 and production use

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I use some of the polymer 0.5 components in production. In the console are emited some deprications related to deep and shadow dom. So i was wondering if 0.5 components are based on experimental apis? Is it posible that the components brake totally in near future? If this happen, can we force the lib to use the polifil for every browser?

I also see some of this deprications logged in the console when I open the 1.0 polymer components on the polymer.org web page. Are this components also not stable and can have big api changes in neer future?

Tnx 
Blaze

output in console:

/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
app.js:418 
homepage_elements.vulcanized.js:1 ::shadow pseudo-element is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.

Comment: Until it is ratified by all browsers, I would [avoid using Web Components](http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/you-should-not-be-using-webcomponents-yet) yet. It's a standard pushed by Google with Standard documents written by Google employees only with no collab between the different manufacturers. If you try to maintain it, you'll maintain the bugs in the polyfill and wonder if it's the API or the Polyfill. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yea, I think also the same. But I was kindof pushed to use them :) Hope the 1.0 will make it as a close to the real standard...

Answer (score 2):

Polymer 0.5 uses deprecated CSS selectors. See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498405
and the Chrome developers seem to be eager to get rid of it since a while.

I don't know about the strategy for polyfills.

Polymer 1.x also used these selectors for a few things and was working on getting them replaced by newer things. I think they are only rarely or not used at all anymore by the elements provided by the Polymer team https://elements.polymer-project.org/ I don't know about other vendors but I guess they will migrate away from these selectors as well soon.

Polymer 1.x is definitely stable. If you want to use something for production use Polymer 1.x.

Comment: Hi Günter, so you think that if moved to 1.0 at least some period there would be no problems like this :) 
I tried to move some of the logic last days and I was surprised that the normal dynamic creation of elements is not working for 1.0. exp:
var g = dom.createElement("paper-radio-group");
g.appendChild(dom.createElement("paper-radio-button"));

the group element was holding the radio button but when clicked it was removed...

Is 1.0 not supporting dynamic creation-usage of elements? Any idea on this one?

Comment: I think Polymer does quite a good job at providing newest features and maintaining compatibility. Some things turned out quite different as expected and not everything is easy to polyfill. `dom.createElement()` is definitely supported. No idea why it's not working for you.